# input Tag returning Empty String on using value property

Tags: javascript, html

```js
// Add tasks to my todo list
let inputTask = document.getElementById('add-task').value;
let inputStatus = document.getElementById('add-status').value;

const addtasks = document.getElementById('task-add-btn').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    let newEntry = {
        title : inputTask,
        status : inputStatus
    }
    console.log(newEntry);
});
```

```html
<input type='text', id='add-task', placeholder="Add TODO Task">
<input type="text", id ='add-status', placeholder="Status True/False">
<div id="task-add">
   <button id='task-add-btn' class="btn">Add Tasks</button>
</div>
```

Here I want to access values in the input field. But I am getting results as empty strings. Can Someone help??

[image]

Comment: @PersonWhoIsStuck When I type some text in input boxes, do values not get updated???

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

`value` is in the wrong place.

```js
// Add tasks to my todo list
const inputTask = document.getElementById('add-task')
const inputStatus = document.getElementById('add-status')

const addtasks = document.getElementById('task-add-btn').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    let newEntry = {
        title : inputTask.value,
        status : inputStatus.value,
    }
    console.log(newEntry);
});
```

```html
<input type='text', id='add-task', placeholder="Add TODO Task">
<input type="text", id ='add-status', placeholder="Status True/False">
<div id="task-add">
   <button id='task-add-btn' class="btn">Add Tasks</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the values of the inputs before anything has been typed into them. You need to get the values when the button is clicked.

```js
// Add tasks to my todo list
let inputTask = document.getElementById('add-task');
let inputStatus = document.getElementById('add-status');

const addtasks = document.getElementById('task-add-btn').addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    let newEntry = {
        title : inputTask.value,
        status : inputStatus.value
    }
    console.log(newEntry);
});
```

```html
<input type='text', id='add-task', placeholder="Add TODO Task">
<input type="text", id ='add-status', placeholder="Status True/False">
<div id="task-add">
   <button id='task-add-btn' class="btn">Add Tasks</button>
</div>
```